# merge regex constructs

Tags: java, regex

I know this question been asked before, however the solutions I found don't work for me. I'm writing a simple program in which one of the methods takes the user input and checks if it contains any characters other than letters (*e.g.*, number or special characters). My first solution goes like this:

```
public boolean charFinder(String inputString) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("0-9", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(inputString);

    return m.find() || m2.find();
}
```

And it works perfectly fine, but I want to make it more elegant. So, I tried this:

```
public boolean charFinder(String inputString) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W | \\d", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);

    return m.find();
}
```

And this doesn't work. Did I merge the regexes correctly?

Comment: If you're looking for anything that's not a letter you can use: `[^a-zA-Z]` (or with the case insensitive option, `[^a-z]`).  If you also need to allow accented characters, this approach is trickier (and you'd have to decide, do you want all accented characters, or some subset).  There's some good info here: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the spaces in `"\\W | \\d"`, or they will be treated as part of the pattern you are trying to match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W|\\d", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Also note that `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` is irrelevant here because `\W` is already case-insensitive and `\d` doesn't match letters, anyway.

Comment: @novice Glad to help! Please remember to tick the checkmark on the left to accept the answer.

Comment: All done, I do apologize, I don't use stackoverflow often. Also thank you for checking typos and grammar. All the best!